# Android contentView disable user interaction?

Tags: android, android-activity, user-interaction

I want to disable the user interaction in an activity so that the user cannot touch the view/ subviews inside the content view of the activity. Is there any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add a blank dialog on top of your activity like this:

```
overlayDialog = new Dialog(context, android.R.style.Theme_Panel);
overlayDialog.show();
```

and when you don't need it any more, call

```
 overlayDialog.dismiss();
```